# css3 rotating words align center

Tags: css, position, alignment, text-align

I have used the perfect codrops css3 rotating words according to my needs, but I can´t make the appearing words align right in the center. All I need is make the sentence align in center and so the rotating words.

But because it´s position absolute, and floating left, the word starts on left 50% position.

Can anyone help with this? I have tryied a lot of experiments but nothing seems to work.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nzAPr/

Comment: For others want to know how to do it, this fiddle has the right version. http://jsfiddle.net/UXzRE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the container to position:relative and the span to 100% seemed to work.

```
.rw-words{
display: block;
position: relative;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/9Xubs/

Comment: Willem, doesn´t work here! The span is now start 50% left of the container. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/TEEpd/

Comment: Thanks Willem, you point me in the right direction. Using margin-left: -50% in the span aligns left to the container.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the indent here:

```
.rw-words{
    display: block;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But that´s not the problem. I remove it and doesn´t work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still looking for a solution for this. 
The animation can only set a centre start point and that's why your words show up shiftet to the right.
You can fix that if you give every  child a negative margin and space it out manually.
This is what I got when I was playing around with the code:http://jsfiddle.net/9Xubs/109/ `margin-left: -35px;`